# how to load more cells in tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

i am writing a iPad application and displaying the tableView in my application. I have two options in tableview:

1. `includeAll`
2. `ExcludeAll`

Once i click the `IncludeAll` all cells should be selected. I am loading more then 10000 records. once i select the include all i got one error message.

error message is

```
malloc: *** mmap(size=2097152) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Comment: Add some code example pls

Answer (score 3):

Googling will reveal quite a few tutorials on using instruments to understand what is going on with your memory:

How to debug memory leaks: (tutorial) 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial

And another:
Finding Obj-C memory leaks (video)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R449qEuexNs&feature=related

Probably because your simulator is able to allocate ~500Mb of memory while your iPad is not able to do it. I think you should rethink what you are doing

do you really need so much memory?
isn't it just a calculating bug? (maybe a wrong sizeof or whatever)
in any case this is really too much data to be handled